# SonarQube: False-Positive S100 - Method names should comply with a naming convention

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have onboarded our project to the SonarQube Developers Edition, however, most of our projects have been reported non compliant for `S100` rule : `Method names should comply with a naming convention` which after scanning reporting the issue

> Rename this method name to match the regular expression '
> ^[a-z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.

However, in the old SonarQube community version, everything works fine.

Sample method being flagged as non-compliant:

```
 public ResponseEntity<Void> performCcsIntermediateCalculations(String calcId){
 }
```

Has anyone encountered the same issue? Of course, I can easily disable this rule but it is weird that this issue comes up and quite annoying as this is reporting thousand of times.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a non-printing character in your method names, like `'\u200d'` or `'\ufeff'`?

Comment: @VGR I don't think there are because this is working fine in the community version of the SonarQube. The issue is only reported when this has been migrated to the developer's edition.